# How to plot different colors on a graph with r code depending on x axis

Tags: r, plot, colors

I do not know if this is possible in rstudio. I just want to plot with 2 or more colors, for example; with this simple code,

```
fun <-function (x) {x^2}

plot(fun, xlim = c(-1,1))
```

how can I plot it in a way that it appears for x (-1,0) blue and for x (0,1) red, for example ?

I don´t want to make 2 curves I just want to make one and change the color in it cause I need it for a more complicated case (Feigenbaum diagram) so I don´t want to separate the function, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`ggplot2` has the `stat_function()` which can be used to draw a function. The colouring can be controlled by accessing the computed variable `x`. The `data.frame` specifies the range on the x-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-1, 1)), aes(x, colour = stat(x > 0))) +
  stat_function(fun = ~ .x^2) +
  scale_colour_manual(guide = "none", values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Apparently, the colour is not switched exactly at `x == 0`. Therefore, we may need to increase the number of data points for which the function is computed:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-1, 1)), aes(x, colour = stat(x > 0))) +
  stat_function(fun = ~ .x^2, n = 500) +
  scale_colour_manual(guide = "none", values = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the function is kind of hard, but you can create a temporary data frame with the values to plot and then assign the color to each value. It would be like this:

```
fun <-function (x) {x^2}
fun_col <- function(x) ifelse(x<0,'blue','red')

data_plot = data.frame(x=seq(-1,1,by = 0.01),y = fun(seq(-1,1,by = 0.01)),
                   col =fun_col(seq(-1,1,by = 0.01)))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = x, y = y))+
  geom_line(color = data_plot$col, lwd =2)
```

[image]

Comment: Why hardcode the colors when the intended way of using ggplot would be to assign a variable to color inside `aes`?

Comment: @camille don't get your point, unless you are saying that in the aes you can define a function to assign the colors

Comment: The ggplot paradigm is generally to assign variables to visual encodings such as color. In this case that would mean having a variable in the data that would be associated with a color—not necessarily the name of a color itself—and in that way create a color scale